# Is cooking a chicken pot pie with a low power microwave safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety

The package says do not use with microwaves less than 1100 watts because it won't cook thoroughly. If I cook on a 700 watt microwave for 6 recommended minutes*(1+(1100-700)/700=8 minutes 10 seconds do I risk food poisoning or do I risk it tasting cold in the middle? I don't really know how these pies are made but the brand is banquet.

Comment: What matters most is the internal temperature of the pot pie. I cook all sorts of frozen stuff at 30% power (30% on, 70% off) so that I don't have to stir.

Comment: @MaxW The back states it has to reach 165 degrees. I think that means it's not fully pre-cooked, otherwise it would say till hot. I ate fish last year that gave me food poisoning and lost a full day of work to vomiting. I wonder if it's worth the risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter for food safety how you reach the required temperature, as long as the food doesn't spend too long in the danger zone. Since you've looking at possibly minutes longer this is not a problem for you. Just make sure you know that the internal temperature is high enough when you finish cooking. I would recommend a thermometer.

Answer (score 0):

Microwaves are notorious for cold spots. What is likely the issue is that a low watt microwave will not heat the food to safe temperature without affecting taste. i.e.Uniform cooking. For the entire food product > 165, some parts may have hit far far > 165. i.e. burnt.

Comment: In my experience, high power is more likely to cause hot spots. Warming slightly slower gives the heat the chance to distribute better. (As stirring isn’t an option here.)